# Getting warning in iOS : Format String is not a string literal (potentially insecure)

Tags: objective-c

Format String is not a String literal (potentially insecure)

My code is:

```
[tweetViewController setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:self.url]];
```

Answer (score 5):

You're getting this warning as you're using a variable when only a string literal (usually a format string) is allowed as an argument to this method.

If you don't want to use a format string don't use that method and use the [`absoluteString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURL/absoluteString) method of `NSURL` instead:

```
[tweetViewController setInitialText:[self.url absoluteString]];
```

Or if you do want to use the format method use a format string:

```
[tweetViewController setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"URL: %@", [self.url absoluteString]];
```

Just using `self.url` as the argument for the `%@` will use the `description` method on `NSURL` which might return different results if Apple ever change the result of this method.